# How can I pin down "AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/christos/wordpress/"?

Tags: apache-2.4, permissions

I'm running Apache 2.4.38 on a new Debian 10 VM, and I am getting just 403 errors, saying e.g. `AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/christos/wordpress/`.

At present I have one `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

<Directory /home/christos/wordpress>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/christos/wordpress

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

I also temporarily renamed the `.htaccess` file, to no observable difference.

If I try to load `http://new.example.com/` or `http://new.example.com/index.html` (the latter being to try and temporarily sidestep an obvious DirectoryIndex-related issue), it gets a 403 error with a log saying (for instance):

```
[Tue Jul 14 17:35:37.376815 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 3162:tid 140122797659904] [client ::1:54384] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/christos/wordpress/
```

User `www-data` can see and can read `/home/christos/wordpress/index.html` and `/home/christos/wordpress/index.php`.

Am I missing something? So far as I can tell, I've given permission at least to load `http://new.example.com/index.html`, and I've only gotten 403 errors. This includes both loading `http://new.example.com` from a browser and for that matter a `telnet localhost 80` of `GET / HTTP/1.0`, which just gets the source of the error page when accessed from a browser.

Thanks,

**--UPDATE--**

I may be missing something about the 2.4 syntax. The edited, current `sites-enabled` entry that is still getting the previous permission error is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

ServerName new.example.com

<Directory /home/christos/wordpress>
    Options ExecCGI Indexes FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/christos/wordpress

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

**--FURTHER UPDATE--**

I had some issues with a DNS and a new development server.

I logged into my DNS and added an A record of `new` to catch `new.example.com.` However, there was apparently a pre-existing record matching `new.example.com` and my A record was added in addition to the previous dressing for `new.example.com`.

This meant that my attempts to update `new.example.com` were sometimes going to the development server and sometimes going to the production server, and so I was not logged in to the server I expected when I attempted to get things working on the new server.

I presently am having trouble getting the PHP to execute instead of displaying as source; I've added:

```
AddHandler php7-script .php
```

to the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` entry and to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`, but it isn't displaying yet.

`php` will run from the command line, and I have `libapache2-mod-php` and `libapache2-mod-php7.3` installed, but I haven't knowingly gotten the server to process a `.php` page as PHP executable. (I've made other searches and found e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page, and am digging through it.

Comment: "Order allow,deny    Allow from all", can you replace these by the 2.4 syntax?

Comment: You don't have a servername, it this site the default?  I would also add a "DirectoryIndex index.html".

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Where do I put the 2.4 syntax? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html covers <RequireAll>, if that's what you mean, but I'm getting errors if I put it in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` entry or `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: It should replace the old syntax.  The directroyindex is still missing?

Comment: If you're having a different problem, it's best to answer this one and start a new question. Changing the meaning of the question in the middle after people have already tried to help will just confuse everyone.